# Java RMI and https?

Tags: java, http, https, port, rmi

I am new to enterprise design and client server technologies. Can you get Java RMI to work over the HTTPS port 443? I found some google links to stuff about "tunneling" and using HTTP port 80. Does that mean your RMI calls are getting wrapped and then unwrapped on both ends from HTTP protocol?

Comment: yes, that is what it means.  generally, though, rmi is _not_ the right technology for use outside a lan.  i.e. if you need tunneling, you're probably doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP tunneling is built into RMI. There is no provision for HTTPS tunneling. It's not a good solution anyway as it imposes a 10x latency.